# How to use multiple boolean to filter ssrs tablix

Tags: reporting-services

I have several records in database and those records have two field named finance stage(value =collected) and project stage(value=completed)

Most of the records have both field filled with collected and completed. Therefore i want to create two Boolean parameters which shows/filter only the records having finance value is collected and have project stage is completed when both parameter is true. i have used x++ and wants to filter tablix for that parameter on report.

Any other suggestion will be highly appreciated

Thank you for reading and regards

Comment: My suggestion is if you have control over procedure which are fetching the data then update the procedure and filter the data at the source (at the db) by passing parameters.

Comment: Have you tried using a `WHERE` clause in your query or a Filter on your dataset in SSRS?